# Replace every occurrence of a period in filenames inside long string

Tags: php, regex

```
$text = 'This is a long text containing different image paths like <img src="/site/assets/files/5136/image1.jpg" width="750" />. The text may contain more than one image, here's another one: <img src="/site/assets/files/5136/image1.1.jpg" width="750" />';
```

Please consider the example text above. I'm looking for a good way to replace period characters in filenames inside a string, that may contain multiple filenames. 'image1.1.jpg' should become 'image1_1.jpg', so the period should be replaced by an underscore. Only period characters that belong to a filename should be replaced. The filename always looks like this:

/site/assets/files/**5136**/**image1.1.jpg**

/site/assets/files/**425**/**image1.jpg**

/site/assets/files/**6524**/**image2.x.png**

The bold parts are variable, the rest of the path is always the same. A filename may or may not contain a period. The extension is .jpg or .png and I only want to target images.

I would like to use PHP to do this.

Comment: And what did you try so far? Nothing I guess

Comment: Is the file always going to be a jpg or other formats are allowed too?

Comment: Can a file extension contain dots (e.g. `.tar.gz`)? If yes, how can it be distinguished from being part of the filename? Is a filename always surrounded by `"`?

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully answer your questions. @Fallenhero I'm sorry I forgot to mention what I've tried, I agree it's bad form to ask a question without doing that. I'll edit my question in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
$new_text = preg_replace_callback('/(\/site\/assets\/files\/[^\/]+\/)([^\/]+)(\.[a-z0-9]+)/i', function ($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . str_replace('.', '_', $matches[2]) . $matches[3];
}, $text);
```

The regex matches all paths beginning with `/site/assets/files` followed by one more path segment plus a filename ending with an extension separated by a single dot (like `.jpg`, but not `.tar.gz`). The match has three groups: the folder path (`$matches[1]`), the filename (`$matches[2]`) and the extension (`$matches[3]`). `str_replace` is used to replace all dots (`.`) in `$matches[2]` with underscores (`_`).

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, thanks! I have not used preg_replace_callback before, so it did not cross my mind when I was trying various things with preg_replace and preg_match. But it's exactly the kind of function I imagined I would need.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You might want to replace `[a-z0-9]+` with `(jpg|png)` to match only those extensions. Note that the code will change all filenames in the text, not only those inside img tags.

Comment: Thanks, I will add the extensions. It does not really matter if the filenames are outside img tags, because I don't expect there will be any.

Answer (score -1):

The regex is rather tricky:

```
(?:(\/site\/assets\/files\/[^."]+\/[^"\/.]+)\.|\G([^"\/.]+)\.)(?![^."\/]+")
```

Substitute it with `$1$2_`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6ooSwy/1

Comment: Your answer doesn't even consider the thing that, it needs to be inside img tag

Comment: Where does the question state that the replacement shall only be inside an img tag?

Comment: It's a nice regex regardless and I think I could have worked something out with it, but I went with x-ray's answer because it's well explained and ready to go.